# Can spork work with rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, spork

Rake tasks suffer from the same problem as running tests: the Rails bootup process takes a long time before the task is even running.

Is there a way to integrate spork and rake together?

Comment: I added my own answer below for zeus (https://github.com/burke/zeus). There is also the rails/command gem that DHH is working on (https://github.com/rails/commands).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered zeus today. It's the best thing ever, so I'm changing my answer to zeus:

https://github.com/burke/zeus

zeus rake my:special:task

Comment: Fascinating... *opens tricorder*

Answer (score 7):

You can use the irake gem which makes it possible to execute rake tasks from the console.

Add this to Gemfile:

```
gem 'irake'
```

Then bundle and start console

```
$ bundle install
$ rails console
```

...and wait for the Rails environment to load (only once). Then you can do:

```
rake "db:migrate"
```

If you want to list tasks, you can:

```
Rake::Task.tasks.each{|t| puts t.name }; nil
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rake test:units
testdrb -I test/ test/unit/

rake test:functionals
testdrb -I test/ test/functional/

rake test:integration
testdrb -I test/ test/integration/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard out of the box solution as i know.

Rake does not have --drb option and spork can't help here.
Sure, custom solution is possible. This will require extension of rake runner.

I think rake tasks run not so often as tests, that why question is not addressed yet.

Comment: Thanks. I basically want something like spin (https://github.com/jstorimer/spin), which forks a loaded Rails process and all the gems.