# Looking for ruby gem that keeps ruby environment loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, rake

I'm not a fan of waiting for `rake -T` to get back to me. About a year ago, I found a ruby gem -- I think it was called the "Rails Console" or the "Ruby Console" or something like that -- that kept the Rails environment loaded in memory (and reloaded automatically) so that rake tasks including `rails console` were super fast.

I remember when it loaded it had a big ASCII art banner that announced its title. I've done quite a bit of searching with Google, StackOverflow, and the Ruby Toolbox, to no avail. Does anyone remember the project? Did it die, get replaced, or get absorbed into another project? Do you know of a good alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can spork work with rake tasks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614621/can-spork-work-with-rake-tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be thinking of [rake-sh](https://github.com/jugyo/rake-sh).

And you'll need to do [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268518/uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-in-ruby-gem) for Ruby 1.9.